# Export list in Access or Excel back into SharePoint [Office 365]

Tags: office-365

I have a SharePoint list that I exported into Access. I made some changes in Access and was wondering if I can export that Access list back into the SharePoint list? I am using Office 365 (not on premise) with SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Access Services in SPOnline only stores data in SQL Server 2012. That is: it cannot use SP list data, except for Importing.

The approach you could use is to move the SQL data over to a SP list using PowerShell or another ADO.Net process.

One source of detail info about this is here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12514.sharepoint-2013-access-services.aspx#Prerequisites